# how to add custom breadcrumbs in wordpress?

Tags: breadcrumb

I need a custom breadcrumb for my account page.Can we do it via functions.php ?

```
add_filter('theme_breadcrumb_args_filter', 'customize_separator_breadcrumbs');

    function customize_separator_breadcrumbs($args) {
        $args['sep'] = ' >> ';
        return $args;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We’ve created a custom function called `get_breadcrumb()` to generate the breadcrumb links. You only need to add the `get_breadcrumb()` function code in `functions.php` file of the current theme.

```
function get_breadcrumb() {
    echo '<a href="'.home_url().'" rel="nofollow">Home</a>';
    if (is_category() || is_single()) {
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        the_category(' &bull; ');
            if (is_single()) {
                echo " &nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp; ";
                the_title();
            }
    } elseif (is_page()) {
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        echo the_title();
    } elseif (is_search()) {
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp;Search Results for... ";
        echo '"<em>';
        echo the_search_query();
        echo '</em>"';
    }
}
```

**Display Breadcrumbs:**
Call the `get_breadcrumb()` function in `single.php` file and others files where you want to display the breadcrumbs on your WordPress site.

```
<div class="breadcrumb"><?php get_breadcrumb(); ?></div>
```

**Styling Breadcrumbs:**
This CSS helps to style the breadcrumbs links.

```css
.breadcrumb {
    padding: 8px 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.breadcrumb a {
    color: #428bca;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

SEE ALSO A USEFULL ANSWERS.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50893992/creating-breadcrumbs-without-a-plugin